# How adding a custom select attribute with translated label depending on a language on frontend

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute

I would like to have a dropdown attribute on product, which has a translatable label depending on the language in backend and in frontend. I managed to display the dropdown in the backend with a translated label depending on the language, but the field is not displayed in search in frontend.

Thanks for your help

I create a mysql setup in **app/code/local/Custom/Shared/sql/upgrade-x.x.x-x.x.x.php**

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'robustness', array(
    'filterable' => true,
    'filterable_in_search' => true,
    'group' => 'Custom',
    'input' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Robustness',
    'required' => true,
    'searchable' => true,
    'source' => 'custom/attribute_source_robustness',
    'type' => 'int',
    'user_defined' => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true
));
```

I also create a Source model in **app/code/local/Custom/Shared/Model/Attribute/Source/Robustness.php**

```
class Custom_Shared_Model_Attribute_Source_Robustness extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = array(
                0 => array(
                    'value' => 0,
                    'label' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('No')
                ),
                1 => array(
                    'value' => 1,
                    'label' => Mage::helper('custom')->__('Yes')
                )
            );
        }

        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

The config in **app/code/local/Custom/Shared/etc/config.xml**

```
<global>
    ...

    <helpers>
        <custom>
            <class>Custom_Shared_Helper</class>
        </custom>
    </helpers>

    <models>
        <custom>
            <class>Custom_Shared_Model</class>
        </custom>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "but the field is not displayed in search in frontend". Not search able? Not in advanced search? Not filterable?